# What graph data structure works fastest with Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

What data structure should I store my graph in to get the best performance from the Dijkstra algorithm?

Object-pointer? Adjacency list? Something else?

I want the lowest O(). Any other tips are appreciated too!

Comment: Theoretical interest, or do you want to implement it? If the later, make sure the structures are neatly encapsulated (so you cn change them later), and just write the simplest version that works. If later performance of the system turns out lacking, and _measurements_ show that this is a bottleneck, then you go looking for better/the best. Knuth's "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" is as true a the day it was uttered.

Comment: @vonbrand I need to implement it, but I'm not looking to optimize it myself. There are well-known optimal implementations and I want to understand those before I begin so I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm with a Fibonacci-heap gives $O(|E|+|V|\log |V|)$ time, and is the fastest implementation known.

As for the representation of the graph - theoretically, Dijkstra may scan the entire graph, so an adjacency list should work best, since from every vertex the algorithm scans all its neighbors.

Comment: I read the first part on Wikipedia but I don't understand what to use the heap for. Do you?

Comment: Wikipedia also says "...making it take only O(log|V|) time instead. The Fibonacci heap improves this to O(|E|+|V|log|V|)." Isn't the second performance WORSE than the first?

Comment: Read chapters 20 and 24 in [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). They explain how to implement the Fibonacci heap. After that, you just use this heap as the priority queue.

Comment: BTW this is all related to my other question about Dijkstra's and priority queues. What is the priority queue and/or heap for? Thanks.

Comment: The priority queue, implemented using a heap, allows you to keep the "frontier" of opened vertices, such that the closest one (w.r.t the distance from $s$) is always at the top. This is equivalent to the standard queue from BFS.

Comment: @Shauli So do you mean the priority queue is used for the unvisited set?

Comment: It's Shaull (double L), and no - it's used to keep the nodes which have been "seen", but their children were not yet explored. This is referred to as the "frontier". Each time you explore a node and see its children, you remove it from the frontier.

Comment: Sorry Shaull! (I have a friend named Shauli). Thanks for the tip. I should have bought CLRS a long time ago but I'll get it today.